# MySQL Order by Decimal with whitespace

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sql-order-by

i dont understand when i try to order by decimal when the PRICE fields are without whitespace everything looks great. But when the user add whitespace between the numbers those fields go to the bottom in the ordering statement.

my price field is varchar also tried with integer and the same problem exist.

Here is an example without whitespace when user inserting like this **23000**:

```
SELECT * FROM `products` ORDER BY CAST(price AS DECIMAL) DESC
```

gives me :
**23000**
20000
13000
10000
5000
etc.

But when the user insert a price like this **23 000** with whitespace between the 3 and the zeros i'm having this :

```
SELECT * FROM `products` ORDER BY CAST(price AS DECIMAL) DESC
```

20000
13000
10000
5000
**and 23 000 like last**

How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the spaces

```
SELECT * FROM `products` 
ORDER BY replace(price,' ','') * 1 DESC
```

but better change your column to `INT`!

Comment: When inserting into DB with whitespace when the column is set to INT its truncating the column.

Comment: Then  remove the spaces before inserting. Just like in my query above with `replace()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TRIM` to remove spaces

```
SELECT * FROM `products` ORDER BY TRIM(price) DESC
```

[**TRIM()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim)

Comment: Yeah but i need it with whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Sanitize your users inputs to only allow integers, ie no spaces. How you do this depends on what frontend you have.

Comment: I need spaces between the prices. I dont wanna crash the frontend.